# Sequence with variable

Tags: oracle

In SQL we will be having a sequence.  But it should be appended to a variable like this

```
M1,M2,M3,M4....
```

Any way of doing this ?

Answer (score 9):

Consider having the prefix stored in a separate column in the table, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
   idprefix VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
   id       NUMBER NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT mypk PRIMARY KEY (idprefix, id)
);
```

In the application, or in a view, you can concatenate the values together. Or, in 11g you can create a virtual column that concatenates them.

I give it 99% odds that someone will say "we want to search for ID 12345 regardless of the prefix" and this design means you can have a nice index lookup instead of a "LIKE '%12345'".

Comment: +1 to answer and APC comment - intelligent keys will usually be considered a bad decision after you live with the design for a while

Comment: So why not create a function index that avoids the prefix? The prefix might actually be useful.  For example:to denote a row prior to a major event like a conversion from a previous system.

Comment: @David: you'll note that I did recommend storing the prefix - albeit in a separate column. Nothing wrong with using a function-based index; alternatively, one could put an index on the virtual column.

Answer (score 4):

```
select 'M' || my_sequence.nextval from dual;
```